# Wrong catch block execution in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception

I'm a C# developer and sometimes PowerShell is just driving me mad.

I have the following code:

```
$script:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try {
    # Some code here
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException] {
    # Print error messages (without stacktrace)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {
    # A thrown string
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.ScriptStackTrace
    exit 1
}
catch {
    # Print proper exception message (including stack trace)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$($_.Exception.GetType().Name): $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.ScriptStackTrace
    exit 1
}
```

The idea is basically:

1. If the exception comes from a call to `Write-Error` use the *first* catch block.
2. If a string is thrown directly, use the *second* catch block.
3. For any other exception, use the *last* catch block.

Now, my problem is with `Write-Error` and the first catch block:

- If I call `Write-Error` within the `try` block, the second catch block is executed (even though the first one should be executed).
- If I remove the *second* catch block and then call `Write-Error`, the correct (first) catch block is used.

Why is that?

I've checked whether `WriteErrorException` and `RuntimeException` are inheriting from each other: They don't (both inherit from `SystemException` but this shouldn't matter).

I've also verified that this behavior is the same in both PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core (6.0).

Comment: What does your `Write-Error` look like?  You can specify the exception thrown by it.  When just doing `Write-Error 'msg' -ea 1`, no exception is thrown, but an error record *is* under `$Error.ErrorRecord`, which is pretty weird.  The source of the parent error record is `System.Management.Automation` which might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It's just `Write-Error 'some message'`. It'll raise an exception because of `$script:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: So it doesn't actually throw an exception, but an error record, that has a child error record, that has an exception.  That might be your issue here

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm not sure on the terminology. When I use `Write-Error` I can catch *something* (doesn't matter to me what you want to call it) and I can catch the correct ... thing of type `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException` if I remove the second catch block.

Comment: Add `-Exception` to your `Write-Error` argument list.  PowerShell works with the `ErrorRecord` .net class instead of just `Exception`.  You can look up `ErrorRecord` on the msdn.

Comment: RuntimeException is the base class, WriteError inherits from this class. Therefore the RuntimeException is valid as well. Have a look on MSDN.

Comment: @f6a4 Could tell me what MSDN article you're referring to? Because I actually looked it up (as I said in the question) and it definitely does not inherit from `RuntimeException` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.writeerrorexception?view=pscore-6.0.0

Comment: "RuntimeException is the base class for exceptions likely to occur while a Monad command is running. public class RuntimeException : SystemException[...]" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runtimeexception?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) "public class WriteErrorException : SystemException" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.writeerrorexception?view=pscore-6.0.0)

Comment: @f6a4 So? I'm confused. You're just repeating what I said: `WriteErrorException` does **not** inherit from `RuntimeException`. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Error` won't throw a terminating error by default, but it will with `ErrorActionPreference` set to `Stop` as you've mentioned.  However, this changes the exception thrown to `ActionPreferenceStopException` which *does* inherit `RuntimeException`

You can still catch the `WriteErrorException` without the `RuntimeException` clause because the inner error record for the `ActionPreferenceStopException` contains the `WriteErrorException`

You can see what I mean by running this:

```
Write-Error 'this is a test' -ErrorAction Stop
$error[0].ErrorRecord.Exception.GetType()
# IsPublic IsSerial Name                        BaseType
# -------- -------- ----                        --------
# True     True     WriteErrorException         System.SystemException
```

But with the `RuntimeException` clause, it will get picked up first because `RuntimeException` is the closest matching exception type.

To workaround this you'd need to either throw a more specific exception or test `$_` within the `RuntimeException` clause.  Here's the latter

```
$script:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try {
    # Some code here
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException] {
    # Print error messages (without stacktrace)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {
    if ($_.Exception -is [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException]) {
        # Print error messages (without stacktrace)
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
        exit 1
    }

    # A thrown string
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.ScriptStackTrace
    exit 1
}
catch {
    # Print proper exception message (including stack trace)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$($_.Exception.GetType().Name): $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.ScriptStackTrace
    exit 1
}
```

You could also add a `ActionPreferenceStopException` clause and test for `$_` there.

**Edit:** Actually, unless you *really* want to use `Write-Error`, you'd be better off just throwing an exception similar to how you would in C#. So instead of `Write-Error`, use:

```
throw [System.InvalidOperationException]::new('This is my message')
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you code doesn't work the way you think it should work. Have you tried it with calling `Write-Error`?

Comment: My bad, looks like the `ActionPreferenceException` gets unwrapped when it's passed to the catch block.  I've updated the example, the only difference was changing `$_.ErrorRecord.Exception` to `$_.Exception` in the `-in` statement.

Comment: Looks better. Now, if you throw a real exception (`throw [System.InvalidOperationException]::new('This is my message')`), you still end up in the second catch block. What about that?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski That's interesting.  If you add a catch clause for `InvalidOperationException` it will work as expected, but your right it does trigger the second clause without that.  My guess is that it's due to all exceptions needing to be wrapped in a `RuntimeException` of some sort under the hood.  That seems like a bug, and it may be best to avoid catching `RuntimeException` directly.